# update and delete using buttons on recyclerview firebase

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, google-cloud-firestore

good day to every Dev,
i am working on a project called e-School i am having hard time with firebase adapter and the crud opertations, i have a cardview inside a recyclerview an  "update" & "delete" button on that cardview, i want to trigger `Button edit_t` & `Button delete_t` image link is here  [Check Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83Z1R.png) and also firebase structure here [db image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlQ8h.png) but i am unable to make the buttons work help is needed!
code is follow

//TeacherViewHolder.java

```
public class TeachersViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
public CircleImageView teacherImage;
public TextView teacherName,teacherDesignation;

public TeachersViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    teacherImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_teacher);
    teacherName =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.teacher_nome);
    teacherDesignation = itemView.findViewById(R.id.teacher_designation);
}}
```

//TeachersAdapter.java

```
public class TeachersAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TeachersAdapter.TeacherAdapterViewHolder> {

private ProgressDialog LoadingBar;
FirebaseAuth teacherAuth;
DatabaseReference teacherRef;
FirebaseDatabase db;

public Context c;
public ArrayList<Modal_Teachers> arrayList;

public TeachersAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Modal_Teachers> arrayList){
    this.c= c;
    this.arrayList = arrayList;

}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return arrayList.size();
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public TeacherAdapterViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_teachers,parent, false);
    Button edit_t = v.findViewById(R.id.teacher_edit);
    Button delete_t = v.findViewById(R.id.teacher_edit);
    return new TeacherAdapterViewHolder(v);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final TeacherAdapterViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final Modal_Teachers sTeachers = arrayList.get(position);
    holder.teacherName.setText(sTeachers.getName());
    holder.teacherDesignation.setText(sTeachers.getQualification());
    Picasso.get().load(sTeachers.getPhotourl()).into(holder.teacherImage);


public class TeacherAdapterViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public CircleImageView teacherImage;
    public TextView teacherName,
            teacherDesignation;
    public Button edit_t, delete_t;

    public TeacherAdapterViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {

        super(itemView);
        teacherImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_teacher);
        teacherName =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.teacher_nome);
        teacherDesignation = itemView.findViewById(R.id.teacher_designation);
        edit_t = itemView.findViewById(R.id.teacher_edit);
        delete_t = itemView.findViewById(R.id.teacher_delete);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So guys i was trying to get rid of this, i experimented writing alot of code and finally got the solution and here is the solution.....
in `TeachersAdapter.java` in `onBindViewHolder` There is a little line of code to be written in order to get our buttons work the code is as follow....also the image links of the next activity are somewhere here [clicking on update button in recyclerview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOvh4.png) & here [getting reference of user & moving to next activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbMkp.png)

TeachersAdapter.java

```
       holder.edit_t.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent goUpdateTeacher = new Intent(holder.edit_t.getContext(), UpdateTeacher.class);
            goUpdateTeacher.putExtra("photourl", sTeachers.getPhotourl());
            goUpdateTeacher.putExtra("teacherName", sTeachers.getName());
            goUpdateTeacher.putExtra("teacherDesignation", sTeachers.getQualification());

            holder.edit_t.getContext().startActivity(goUpdateTeacher);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Good work! If this solved your issue, please consider accepting your own answer.